# Copying related tables, without the primary key but preserving the foreign key relationship

Tags: mysql

I have a badly designed database in hands. It has some tables with are related to each other by fields that were supposed to be foreign keys. For example, if they were to tables, each of them have a primary key, and the second contains the a column which was supposed to be a foreign key, but it is just a filed manually controlled to maintain the relationship.

My problem is finding a way to copy those tables to a second database, which have the same tables, with its own entries.

I tough about a select statement, excluding the primary key, and putting NULL in the first column(the primary key). By doing so, I could dump the records into a CVS and send it to the second DB, which would use automatic increment for the primary key. However, this would be a problem for the second table, as I would not know the new keys.

`|  Table A  |    |  Table B   |
  | keyA    |      | keyB    | 
  | fields  |      | keyA    |`

Comment: After copying as you suggested, you will have to add the relation again yourself. So if the data is not corrupt right now, that should not be a big issue.

Comment: The problem is to know the new keys. because the primary keys would change, so I would need a way to know the new value and to store on the second table again.

Comment: So, you are saying I would need to do it manually? I am thinking about writing a program for that, but a SQL solution would be way better.

Comment: only way you could really do it would be to add an `old_id` field to the tables on the new database, insert all the new records with auto increment primary keys, and populate the `old_id` field with the old id, then join the two tables on the `old_id` fields, and populate the fks with the new pks

Comment: You can clone the tables very quick in SQL. The key relationship can be queried information_schema.INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN. SO yes, you could write a quick script. You just have to skip all the PRIMARY keys (or most) in your case.